# Next Song Button For External Media Player?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Feel free to edit title.

Ok so i'm trying to create a short key button that skips to the next song of any media player? like what some keyboards have as in FN + F11 and it goes to next song is there anyway to integrate that into c# for my own keyboard? i have this code so far but all its doing is posting a msg onto the textbox1.

```
// Structure contain information about low-level keyboard input event 
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
{
    public Keys key;
    public int scanCode;
    public int flags;
    public int time;
    public IntPtr extra;
}
//System level functions to be used for hook and unhook keyboard input  
private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int id, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hook);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hook, int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);
//Declaring Global objects     
private IntPtr ptrHook;
private LowLevelKeyboardProc objKeyboardProcess;

private IntPtr captureKey(int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lp, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));

        // Keys
        if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.F10 && ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
            a += 1;
            c += 1;
            textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(c) + ". " + "Previous Song" + Environment.NewLine;
            PrevSongCount.Text = Convert.ToString(a);
            AllUpCount.Text = Convert.ToString(c);
            return (IntPtr)1;
        }
        if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.F11 && ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
            b += 1;
            c += 1;
            textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(c) + ". " + "Next Song" + Environment.NewLine;
            NextSongCount.Text = Convert.ToString(b);
            AllUpCount.Text = Convert.ToString(c);
            return (IntPtr)1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(ptrHook, nCode, wp, lp);
}
bool HasAltModifier(int flags)
{
    return (flags & 0x20) == 0x20;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This was not as easy as I thought. But finally I managed to do it and the solution was shockingly simple.

After compiling this you are using the venerable virtual media keyboard codes. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

I used this cmd line prog for my microsoft natural keyboard which does not have media keys but has 5 programmable keys and to get it to work you hack the registry

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\IntelliType Pro\EventMapping\82 or

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\IntelliType Pro\ModelSpecific\1016\EventMapping\82

where the 81 is just one of the dynamic keys (78-82)
and put the value previous or next into the Arguments key.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace NxtTrack
{    
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void keybd_event(byte vkCode, byte scanCode, int flags, IntPtr extraInfo);

    enum TrackMove
    {
        Previous,Next
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TrackMove trackMove;

        try
        {
            if(args[0].ToLower().Contains("previous"))
                trackMove = TrackMove.Previous;
            else if(args[0].ToLower().Contains("next"))
                trackMove = TrackMove.Next;
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("wrong param");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Params needed: Next or Previous");
            return;
        }
        TrackKeys(trackMove);
    }

    private static void TrackKeys(TrackMove trackMove)
    {
        //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

        byte msg = trackMove == TrackMove.Previous ? (byte)0xB1 : (byte)0xB0;
        keybd_event(msg, 0x45, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It works fine with windows Media Player, vlc and Spotify, haven't tryied others. But it will not respond if youre in Visual studio 2012 programming something which is most of my working day ??? Anyone have an idea to solve that??